# convergence and closeness of two estimators

Tags: probability, convergence

Suppose

$\hat{\theta}_n$ is the estimator obtained by solving $g_n(\theta) = 0$

$\tilde{\theta}_n$ is the estimator obtained by solving $h_n(\theta) = 0$

If $g_n(\theta) = h_n(\theta) + o_p(n^{\alpha})$

Can I conclude that $\hat{\theta}_n = \tilde{\theta}_n + o_p(n^{\alpha})$ ?

If not, on what condition can I make this conclusion? Will continuity of $g_n$ and $h_n$ be enough? And does $\alpha$ need to be 0?